# Raytracing and Surface normals

Tags: c++, 3d, raytracing

I am having a weird problem in the below code snippet. I am trying to use surface normals of a sphere(outward) to determine the correct ray intersection and eliminate those that are hitting from within the sphere. for some strange reason this only works correctly when I flip my surface normal to be inwards and change my inequality to be >= 0 and I'm struggling to see what I'm doing wrong.

```
if (discriminant >= 0) {
  float solution_1 = (-b + sqrt(discriminant)) / 2 * a;
  Vec3 normal_1 = (m_Centre, r.direction() * solution_1);
  if (dot(normal_1, r.direction()) <= 0) {
    colour_depth.first = m_Colour;
    colour_depth.second = (r.direction() * solution_1)[2];
    return colour_depth;
  }

  float solution_2 = (-b - sqrt(discriminant)) / 2 * a;
  Vec3 Normal_2 = (m_Centre, r.direction() * solution_2);
  if (dot(Normal_2, r.direction()) <= 0) {
    colour_depth.first = m_Colour;
    colour_depth.second = (r.direction() * solution_2)[2];
    return colour_depth;
  }
  else {
    colour_depth.first = Vec3(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    colour_depth.second = -10000.f;
    return colour_depth;
  }
}
else {
  colour_depth.first = Vec3(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
  colour_depth.second = -1000000.f;
  return colour_depth;
}
}

Vec3 Normal(Vec3 Origin, Vec3 Intersection) {
  Vec3 n = (Intersection - Origin).normalise();
  return n;
}
```

Comment: `Vec3 normal_1 = (m_Centre, r.direction() * solution_1)` is equivalent to `Vec3 normal_1 = r.direction() * solution_1`. I think you meant `Vec3 normal_1(m_Centre, r.direction() * solution_1);`

Comment: That's what I have in the code though isn't it. Also what is confusing me is the fact the inequality must be correct since if I flipped my normal and the inequality then everything works. Which suggests the values are indeed lesser than zero.

Comment: The faulty line *with* `=` is what you have in your code. The line without it is what you should have. (`(a,b)`evaluates `a`, throws away the result, and returns the value of `b`.) Fix that first, then see what the next problem could be.

Comment: I'm sorry I just realised I wasn't calling the member function Normal. Thank you. well now I'm back to square one and my solution is not correctly eliminating the inside rays. back to the drawing board :(